# Is the closure a function outside or a function wrapped inside in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I saw a lot of articles say that the inner function can be called a closure When it is wrapped in another function. For example, a closure will be `inner` in the following code.

```
function outer () {
  const outer = `I see the outer variable!`

  return function inner() {
    console.log(outer)
  }
}
```

But when I debug it in Chrome devtool, it shows that Closure is `outer` function. So is the closure a function outside or inside exactly?
[image]

Comment: What that's showing is the variables that are in the closed environment of the `outer` function.

Answer (score 0):

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In
> other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope
> from an inner function.

See [Closures - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)